# Pre-Bologna French degree

Tags: phd, france, bologna-process

Can anyone refer me to materials to determine what a habilitation (HDR) earned in France, pre-Bologna circa 1993, would be equivalent to in the US?  What would the US equivalent be for someone that did NOT earn a doctorate, only the HDR.  Any references online or journals, etc. are appreciated.

Comment: Why isn't this a duplicate of this earlier question? https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/161997/75368. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habilitation

Comment: @Buffy: It's not a duplicate because generally a habilitation is obtained after a doctorate. The particular situation described might even be impossible in some countries.

Comment: @DanFox, so, in the past was it possible to gain habilitation without a doctorate?

Comment: yes, in France you could get a habilitation without a phd.  this is pre-bologna